# Audio driver Works in Win7 64-bits but doesn't work in Win XP 64

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, 64-bit, audio, windows-7

My computer can play audio files in Windows Xp 32-bits, Windows Vista 32-bits, Windows Seven 64-bits but cannot do that in Windows Xp 64-bits. I've tried a lot of drivers.
Hardware: Realtek ALC662 @ SiS High Definition Audio Controller
I don't know what to do...

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are instlling windows XP 32 and 64, vista 32 and 64, and windows 7 32 and 64 bit OS's... why not just pick one that works and stick with it?

Comment: `I don't know what to do...` - stick to Windows 7 64-bit ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not just the 32-bit vs 64-bit issue.  Windows 7 uses a completely different audio system than windows XP.  Windows XP x64 is a niche product, and a lot of hardware makers just haven't got around to producing drivers for it and likely never will. I hate to say it, but it sounds like you're working on a lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Joel said.

Windows XP x64 is based off of Windows 2003 x64, so if they have any Windows 2003 drivers, you may have luck with that.

However, look at the original specification of your motherboard - does it say compatible with Windows XP x64? If it does, it could be worth asking the place you got it from for help (or a refund) if drivers are available somewhere.

I would never install drivers that are not compatible/meant for the hardware you have. It can lead to problems down the line.